# Objective-C JSON Data Quotation marks

Tags: android, objective-c, ios, json, sbjson

Good afternoon,

I am passing a JSON string to an iOS app and an Android app from a webservice. Business rules dictate that this JSON string CAN contain data with a quotation mark.

```
{"message": [{"MessageID": "22", "CompanyID": "0897001", "MessageText": "this "message" has quotes", "JobID": "BT201-Main-1-031508-134700", "AttachmentCount": "0", "MainDevice": "1"},{"MessageID": "23", "CompanyID": "0897001", "MessageText": "this message has  no quotes", "JobID": "BT201-Main-1-031508-134700", "AttachmentCount": "0", "MainDevice": "1"}]}
```

After doing a little google-ing, I have found that if I want to send data with quotation marks enclosed, I just need to preface the quotation marks inside of the value with a backslash:

```
{"MessageID": "22", "CompanyID": "0897001", "MessageText": "this \"message\" has quotes", "JobID": "BT201-Main-1-031508-134700", "AttachmentCount": "0", "MainDevice": "1"}
```

When the android app gets this JSON, it parses it beautifully. The data displays in the view with quotes and all. Not so with the iOS app. What can I do to the JSON to get the iOS app to properly parse the JSON? I am currently using SBJSON in my iOS app. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could describe what does happen (especially if you're getting an error back), and show the code you're using to deserialize this input?

Comment: I'm sorry about that. As I walk through the parsing process, the parser skips the backslash as an escape character, and stops the parsing of the value at the next quotation mark: "this \". It finds no comma after what it considers an end quote, and throws an "Object Key String Expected" error (part of the SBJsonParser). I hope that this helps!

Comment: Which version of SBJson are you using?

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem with iOS. Are you getting the backslash as well? In this case, what about a pattern replacement?

Comment: I am getting the JSON string back just the way that it looks, but it is not handling the backslash as an escape character, and stops parsing the value at the next quotation mark.

Comment: Which version of SBJson are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Can you see that the JSON you are feeding the parser actually has the \" in it? How is the JSON generated? SBJson does handle embedded quotes correctly. Here's a link to the particular part of the test suite that explicitly checks for it:

https://github.com/stig/json-framework/tree/master/Tests/Data/valid/string/escapes